# How to access a movieclip via "stage" property?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

There is a `movieclip ("abc_Mc")` on stage. I know, to access it, i can simply use Document class, and add a variable named `abc_Mc` and thus can access it.

But i wanna access it via `stage` property. ( As it must be a child of stage)

I added a movieclip "a_Mc" on authoring time, and used the following code :

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

for ( var i = 0  ; i<stage.numChildren ; i++)
{
var a = stage.getChildByName("a_Mc")
var b = stage.getChildAt(i) ;
trace(a)
trace(b)
}
```

//output :
   //null
   //[object MainTimeline]

I am not getting the value of that movieclip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the timeline you must first use `stage.getChildAt(0);`.  This gives you the timeline, which will contain your MovieClip.

```
var timeline:DisplayObject = stage.getChildAt(0);
trace(timeline.abc_Mc);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You should have said that you dragged your MovieClip to the stage from the Flash IDE - these instances will not be added directly to the stage, but to a MainTimeline object, which is itself added to the stage.

Use `stage.getChildAt (0)` to get the timeline, then use `timeline.getChildByName("a_MC")`.